# How to assemble a DB8 antenna balun

Tags: antenna, antenna-system, balun

I have an old (2009) Antenna Direct DB8 antenna that has never worked great. I would get good reception then poor reception and not due to atmospherics. I finally decided to take it down and inspect. I took off the straps with the balun on it and something was rattling around in the black case. I unscrewed the screws on the back before opening thinking the case would not open with the screws in place (wrong). When I opened it, I found 3 nuts inside. The circuit board was in the shell at the top of the pic with the copper pads facing up. There are only two bolts. Can anyone tell me how to reassemble the Balun? I'm not sure where each nut should go.pics below.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a gamma match device, not a BaLun; and it's looks to be fabricated in a way that can only go back together one way, that is with each copper pad on the printed circuit board making contact with the driven element of the antenna, through the screws.  So if you were having problems before, it was likely due to lose connections between the copper pads on the gamma match and the antenna element.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll give it a try.